# How to create a table(in RDBMS) of a data class in Kotlin?

Tags: sql, database, kotlin, jdbc, data-class

I have a data class `PostInfo.kt` in Kotlin like this:

```
@DBUniqueKeyColumns(["postId"])
data class PostInfo{
    val postId: Int,
    @DBDataType("varchar(64)")
    val postContent: String,
    @DBDataType("varchar(10)")
    val postAuthor: String,
}
```

Say, I have a DbHost and I want to run some SQL commands(CRUD), say like this:

```
fun createTable(tableName: string){
    myDbConnection.executeSqlQueryUsingJDBC("create table "+tableName);
    // or a better way to use the data class and create a table.
}
```

What are the ways to do it?

In other words. If I have a data class defined like above in Kotlin, is there a way I can use it directly to create, delete, manipulate SQL Database?

Answer (score -1):

With an Object/Relational Mapper is this possible, like Exposed, an ORM framework for Kotlin:

https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed

or Hibernate (hibernate.org/orm) or Spring Boot/Spring Data (spring.io/projects/spring-data-jpa)

With Spring Boot a class looks like this:

```
@Entity
class User(
    var login: String,
    var firstname: String,
    var lastname: String,
    var description: String? = null,
    @Id @GeneratedValue var id: Long? = null)
```

More information about Kotlin with Spring Boot

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/